# Representing values in Observation and Action space for multiple objects

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I'm just wondering how I'd set up the observation and action spaces for representing 5 people who can sit at 5 different tables. They start at the first table and I want them to learn how to find their own table by moving up or down one table. I'm using an array of [5,0,0,0,0], not sure how I'd be able to represent the allowable moves or the observation space.